# Align headline to card

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a problem aligning simple headline to card in Bootstrap 4:
[image]

I want to have text start at the same place where left side of the card starts. I tried to put text inside form, inside card, but none of these worked.

Here's the actual code:

```
<div>
  <div class="search-panel">
    <div style="max-width:960px; padding-top: 75px" class="row">
      <div>
        <h1 style="color: white">
          Find unique work and</br>
          forget about boring recruitment
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="card col-8">
        <div class="card-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-row mb-2">
              <div class="form-group col">
                <label for="inputEmail4">Job Category</label>
                <select style="width:100%" class="form-control">
                  <option>Backend developer</option>
                  <option>Frontend developer</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col">
                <label for="inputEmail4">Technology</label>
                <select style="width:100%" class="form-control">
                  <option>Javascript</option>
                  <option>C++</option>
                  <option>more to come</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col">
                <label for="inputEmail4">Location</label>
                <select style="width:100%" class="form-control">
                  <option>Milan</option>
                  <option>London</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-info float-right mt-3 mb-3">1,315 results</button>
            </div><small class="float-left">
              <router-link to="/refinesearch">Refine search</router-link></small>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I bet there is some simple solution for that, but they are hard to find.

Comment: The card should be inside the `col-8`. The `justify-content-center` is moving the entire col to the right... remove that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work fine:

```css
body, html {
 background-color: #e3e3e3;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<style>
body {
 background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

</style>

<body>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-8 title p-0">
    <h1 style="color: white"> Find unique work and<br/>
      forget about boring recruitment </h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="search-panel">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="card col-8">
      <div class="card-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-row mb-2">
            <div class="form-group col">
              <label for="inputEmail4">Job Category</label>
              <select style="width:100%" class="form-control">
                <option>Backend developer</option>
                <option>Frontend developer</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col">
              <label for="inputEmail4">Technology</label>
              <select style="width:100%" class="form-control">
                <option>Javascript</option>
                <option>C++</option>
                <option>more to come</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col">
              <label for="inputEmail4">Location</label>
              <select style="width:100%" class="form-control">
                <option>Milan</option>
                <option>London</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-info float-right mt-3 mb-3">1,315 results</button>
          </div>
          <small class="float-left">
          <router-link to="/refinesearch">Refine search</router-link>
          </small>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm still struggling why didn't I found that out - such a simple thing. Thanks a lot! You saved me a lot of time :)